# SwiftUI Binding to parent view re-renders child view

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, combine

I have a child view that is given a binding from the parent view, which controls the app's sidebar menu. When I click the button to toggle showSidebar and open the menu, my vm is re-created because the view is re-rendered? Is there a way to do this without affecting the view model?

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject private var vm: OnboardingViewModel
    @State private var filtering = false
    @Binding var showSidebar: Bool

init(showSidebar: Binding<Bool>) {
    self._showSidebar = showSidebar
    self.vm = OnboardingViewModel()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try...

Change this

```
@ObservedObject private var vm: OnboardingViewModel
```

to

```
@StateObject private var vm: OnboardingViewModel = OnboardingViewModel()
```

and get rid of

```
init(showSidebar: Binding<Bool>) {
    self._showSidebar = showSidebar
    self.vm = OnboardingViewModel()
}
```

> it’s unsafe to create an observed object inside a view without an @StateObject

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: I was hoping to avoid StateObjects to keep backward compatibility with iOS 13+ but I may have to give it a try. What if the StateObject is initially dependent on some value from the parent View?

Comment: I guess at that point it will be refreshing based off the parent value anyways so an ObservableObject would be the go-to in that case?

Comment: I would need an example to explain further but there are plenty of SO questions on the topic. You can create the object in `@State var vm: ObservableObject = OnboardingViewModel()` and then pass to `@ObservedObject var vm: OnboardingViewModel`. `struct` are immutable and can be re-created at SwiftUI's discretion. You have to provide a source of truth  that maintains the integrity of the object. There are many ways of doing this. Singletons (less desirable), variables in a `class`, etc